# DIODES' AP2411 high-side switch usage

Tags: high-side

I built circuit for DIODES' AP2411 high-side switch on a solderless test board and connected the output to 20 ohm resistor to ground. Input voltage is 3.3V from a lab power supply. The output voltage i get is about 2.8V. Is that normal to lose almost 0.5V?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: For a solderless breadboard?  Depends how good it is, but that only requires ~3 ohms resistance, which sounds plausible to me.

Comment: Have you verified the 200 ohm ground? This device current limits to 2.5 amps so if you have a 1.12 ohm load, that would be the current limiter functioning?